# Binary String to Array to HEX Color

Tags: php, binary

Trying to import some color pallets from a program which stores them in binary format. I need them to be split and converted to hex. I didn't think it would be too difficult after seeing this tool: https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/binary-to-hex-converter, but I am not getting the results I expected.

```
$color = "[00001010,11101111,11000001,00000000,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,01100000,00000000,10010000,00000000,11111111,11111111,01100000,00000000,10010000,00000000,11111111,11111111,01100000,00000000,10010000,00000000,11111111,11111111,01100000,00000000,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,01100000,00000000,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,10001010,00000000,11000000,00000000,11111111,11111111,10001010,00000000,11000000,00000000,11111111,11111111,10001010,00000000,11000000,00000000,11111111,11111111,11000000,00000000,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,10010000,00000000,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,01110011,01110101,01110010,01100111,01100101,01110010,01111001,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,10101110,00000000,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,10101110,00000000,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11000000,00000000,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11000000,00000000,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,11000000,11000000,11000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000]";
$new_arr = array_map('trim', explode(',', trim($color, '[]')));

$arr = array_chunk($new_arr, 3);

foreach($arr as $bingroup){
    print("<div style='position:absolute;height:20px;width:20px;background:#");
    foreach($bingroup as $binitem){

    $hex = bin2hex ($binitem);
    print($hex);
    }
    print("'></div>");
}
```

So I import the string, trim, explode it to an array, group them into groups of 3 and then run over it with a couple foreach loops using `bin2hex()` -> simple right? Why then am I getting

```
<div style="position:absolute;height:20px;width:20px;background:#303030303130313031313130313131313131303030303031"></div>
```

Comment: you tried to debug this? find out whats happening with bingroup and binitem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, this is happening as you want

```
<?php  

$color = "[00001010,11101111,11000001,00000000,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,01100000,00000000,10010000,00000000,11111111,11111111,01100000,00000000,10010000,00000000,11111111,11111111,01100000,00000000,10010000,00000000,11111111,11111111,01100000,00000000,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,01100000,00000000,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,10001010,00000000,11000000,00000000,11111111,11111111,10001010,00000000,11000000,00000000,11111111,11111111,10001010,00000000,11000000,00000000,11111111,11111111,11000000,00000000,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,10010000,00000000,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,01110011,01110101,01110010,01100111,01100101,01110010,01111001,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,10101110,00000000,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,10101110,00000000,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11000000,00000000,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11000000,00000000,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,11000000,11000000,11000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000]";



$new_arr = array_map('trim', explode(',', trim($color, '[]')));

$arr = array_chunk($new_arr, 3);

foreach($arr as $bingroup){
    print("<div style='position:absolute;height:20px;width:20px;background:#");
    foreach($bingroup as $binitem){
    $hex = base_convert($binitem, 2, 16);
        if(strlen($hex) == 1){
            $hex = '0'.$hex;
        }
    print($hex);
    }
    print("'></div>");
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation and I'll give you an up.

Comment: I know, I'm saying an explanation would make this a good answer and not just a code dump.  See the other answer.

Comment: This is the right way. The code from rickdenhaan did work, but oddly it brought back a different color palate than expected. I will have to play with it to figure out what the difference is.

Comment: @Alan well, my code didn't actually add a 0 to single-digit color codes (I just had a note that you might want to add something like that). The code in this answer does have a check for that.

Comment: thanks @Alan for explanation, i am not english so its hard me to explain thats why i just dump the code

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you're not actually converting a *binary number* to hexadecimal, which `bin2hex()` expects. You're trying to convert a *string representation* of a binary number to hexadecimal.

The ASCII character "0" is "30" in hexadecimal, character "1" is "31" in hexadecimal. So converting the *string* "00001010" to hexadecimal using `binhex()` will return the string "3030303031303130".

A workaround to get what you want is to first convert the string to decimal (funnily enough, `bindec()` does support strings) and then go from decimal to hexadecimal:

```
echo dechex(bindec("00001010"));
// "a"
// -> 00001010 in binary = 10 in decimal = "a" in hexadecimal
```

So you need to change this line:

```
// $hex = bin2hex ($binitem);
$hex = dechex(bindec($binitem));
```

CSS either supports single character color codes ("#abc") for all colors or double for all ("#aabbcc"), but not a mixture of the two so you might also need to add an extra check to make sure color codes < 16 will be output as "0a" instead of just "a".

You can use `sprintf()` for this. This formats the decimal (after conversion) as hexadecimal padded with a 0 to 2 characters.

```
$hex = sprintf('%02x', bindec($binitem));
```

Comment: I was going to post this with less explanation, good job explaining.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Thanks, it's refreshing to see a "why does this happen" question instead of a "how do I fix this" question for a change.

Comment: Great explanation, I like the one line simplicity, but for some reason it needed the solution from Ganesh Kandu, which adds in an extra `0` sometimes.

Comment: `printf('%02x', bindec("00001010"));`

Comment: @Alan: This is probably the best answer now.